# Core Data mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification Doesn't Work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ios, core-data

I am writing a Core Data ContextManager for a larger iOS application.  A ContextManager provides an NSManagedContext that is automatically updated when other ContextManagers save their NSMangedContext to the persistent data store.

I have a unit test (TestContextManager) that creates two contexts, adds an object to one, and tests to see if the object appears in the other context.  It doesn't.  **Why does the last test fail?**

Here's the code for a ContextManager and the failing unit test.  The last assert in the unit test fails.  Every other assert passes.  As you can see, the ContextManager relies upon getting a change notification from a different ContextManager and using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` to update itself.  Notice that everything happens on the same thread for this test.

I know the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is being sent and received correctly.  I know the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification has the correct data in its userInfo dictionary.

I have also run this unit test as an application test on an actual device using an SQLite persistent store -- the same assert fails.

Thanks in advance!

ContextManager:

```
#import "ContextManager.h"

@implementation ContextManager

@synthesize context;

#pragma mark - Custom code
- (void)save {

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (self.context != nil) {
        if ([self.context hasChanges] && ![self.context save:&error]) {

            NSAssert1(FALSE, @"Unable to save the managed object context.  UserInfo:\n%@", [error userInfo]);

        } 
    }

    return;
}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (notification.object != self.context) {

        [self.context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

    }

    return;
}

#pragma mark - Overridden NSObject methods
#pragma mark Creating, copying, and deallocating object
- (id)initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
        self.context = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self.context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [context release];
    [super dealloc];
    return;
}

@end
```

TestContextManager:

```
#import "TestContextManager.h"
#import "ContextManager.h"
#import "CoreDataManager.h"

#define TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT @"AManagedObject"

@implementation TestContextManager

- (void)testContextManager {

    CoreDataManager *coreDataManager = [[CoreDataManager alloc] init];
    coreDataManager.storeType = NSInMemoryStoreType;

    ContextManager *contextManagerA = [coreDataManager provideContextManager];
    if (!contextManagerA) STFail(@"CoreDataManager did not provide a context manager.");

    NSManagedObjectContext *contextA = contextManagerA.context;
    if (!contextA) STFail(@"ContextManager did not provide a managed object context.");

    // setA1 has 0 objects (or whatever is initially there).
    NSSet *setA1 = [contextManagerA.context registeredObjects];
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextManagerA.context];

    // setA2 has 1 object.
    NSSet *setA2 = [contextManagerA.context registeredObjects];
    STAssertTrue([setA2 count] == [setA1 count]+1, @"Context provided by ContextManager is not accepting new objects.");
    [contextManagerA save];

    ContextManager *contextManagerB = [coreDataManager provideContextManager];
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextManagerB.context];     
    [contextManagerB save];

    NSSet *setA3 = [contextManagerA.context registeredObjects];

    // setA3 should have 2 objects <=== THIS TEST FAILS
    STAssertTrue([setA3 count] == [setA1 count]+2, @"Context is not updating new objects.");

    [coreDataManager release];    


    return;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually set up the ContextManager to observe the notification for saving a managedObjectContext? You don't show that here so I just wanted to cover the simplest case.

***Sorry***, I should have made this a comment on Erik's post.

Comment: Yes.  This is done in the ContextManager's initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator: method.  I also have used logging to verify that the notifications are being sent and received by the ContextManager.

Comment: Oh wait I just noticed something. The problem is not the merge it's in the test. Your assignment to setA1 & setA2 are resulting in pointing to the same object. You should either make a copy of the registered objects for each or just get the count of each before adding a new object.

Comment: I think that NSManagedContext sends and autoreleased NSSet as a return value to registeredObjects.  But, just in case, I have updated my code per my addition below.  Unfortunately, the test still fails...

Comment: See Scott's solution on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to littleknown for answering my question.  Clearly I need to do some reading on what `registeredObjects` actually returns.  I guess the good news here is that the actual code works -- the unit test was bad...

Here's the unit test that correctly exercises the unit under test AND passes:

```
#import "TestContextManager.h"
#import "ContextManager.h"
#import "CoreDataManager.h"

#define TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT @"AManagedObject"

@implementation TestContextManager

- (void)testContextManager {

    CoreDataManager *coreDataManager = [[CoreDataManager alloc] init];
    coreDataManager.storeType = NSInMemoryStoreType;

    ContextManager *contextManagerA = [coreDataManager provideContextManager];
    if (!contextManagerA) STFail(@"CoreDataManager did not provide a context manager.");

    NSManagedObjectContext *contextA = contextManagerA.context;
    if (!contextA) STFail(@"ContextManager did not provide a managed object context.");

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionA = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextA];

    // make A1 request on an empty context (0 objects)
    NSFetchRequest *requestA1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestA1 setEntity:entityDescriptionA];
    NSError *errorA1 = nil;
    NSArray *arrayA1 = [contextA executeFetchRequest:requestA1 error:&errorA1];
    if (arrayA1 == nil) STFail(@"Fetch request A1 failed.");
    if ([arrayA1 count] != 0) STFail(@"Context A1 is not empty at start of test.");

    // add an object to context A and make request A2
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextManagerA.context];
    NSFetchRequest *requestA2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestA2 setEntity:entityDescriptionA];
    NSError *errorA2 = nil;
    NSArray *arrayA2 = [contextA executeFetchRequest:requestA2 error:&errorA2];
    if (arrayA2 == nil) STFail(@"Fetch request A2 failed.");
    if ([arrayA2 count] != 1) STFail(@"Context A2 did not successfully add an object.");

    // add an object to context B and make request B1
    ContextManager *contextManagerB = [coreDataManager provideContextManager];
    NSManagedObjectContext *contextB = contextManagerB.context;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionB = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextB];
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:TEST_MANAGED_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:contextManagerB.context]; 
    NSFetchRequest *requestB1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestB1 setEntity:entityDescriptionB];
    NSError *errorB1 = nil;
    NSArray *arrayB1 = [contextB executeFetchRequest:requestB1 error:&errorB1];
    if (arrayB1 == nil) STFail(@"Fetch request B1 failed.");
    if ([arrayB1 count] != 1) STFail(@"Context B1 did not successfully add an object.");

    // save contextB
    [contextManagerB save];

    // check if contextA was updated
    NSFetchRequest *requestA3 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestA3 setEntity:entityDescriptionA];
    NSError *errorA3 = nil;
    NSArray *arrayA3 = [contextA executeFetchRequest:requestA3 error:&errorA3];
    if (arrayA3 == nil) STFail(@"Fetch request A3 failed.");
    if ([arrayA3 count] != 2) STFail(@"Context A did not update correctly.");

    [requestA1 release];
    [requestA2 release];
    [requestB1 release];
    [requestA3 release];
    [coreDataManager release];    

    return;
}

@end
```